# Using chrome.storage api from extension script - data is namespaced by page URL?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the chrome.storage api, which is supposed to allow us access to the user's data storage without the need for a background page:

https://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/storage.html

The extension is working fine for any particular page, but it seems like data is stored in such a way that it is not accessible when the extension is loaded for a page with a different URL.

Basic get data code:

```
var key = 'commonKey';
chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(items) {console.log(items);}
```

I'm matching the content script on a URL like http://test.com/ABC, and the data correctly persists across multiple loads of that page. However when I load http://test.com/CDE, it gets and sets a different set of data (and doesn't affect the data loaded on page ABC).

Is there some behavior here that is namespacing the data per URL? I looked through the documentation and other questions but couldn't find anything of the sort.

The manifest looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Test script",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.test.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Could you provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
var key = 'commonKey';
chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(items) {console.log(items);}
```

using key in place of 'commonKey' when setting the data resulted in the data being stored under the string 'key' rather than 'commonKey' as expected. That plus the logic in the rest of the code caused the above behavior.